# Find files containing a text but not the second

Tags: linux, file, command-line, grep

I am looking for a way to find all files containing a 'texta' but do not contain a 'textb'.

I tried something like:

```
grep -Ri 'texta' * | grep -v 'textb' *
```

I am quite new on linux command line. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this approach should be working:

```
grep "texta" * -Ril | while read file; do grep -qi "textb" "$file" || echo "$file"; done;
```

The -l options prints out the files only, -q tells grep to be quiet.

Comment: Cool, I ll try out first thing on monday when I get in my office. Thanks. I ll come back and accept the answer then,